# Why can't we log items regardless of dev mode?

Tags: plugin-development, import, logging

Unfortunatley we need to develop an Import plug-in helper with dev mode OFF, for - according to Brad at P&T:

> devMode uses a lot more memory on a given PHP request and importing
>   probably already requires significant memory, so my guess is that
>   you're running into your php.ini file's memory_limit or
>   max_execution_time limits or something similar.

The Import plug-in is definitely a resource pig. We can't get it to work *at all* in dev mode. But we need to develop a plug-in using its hooks to help with things it can't handle in our situation (tables, dates, switches) so we're in a tough spot.

According to [this](https://straightupcraft.com/articles/how-do-i-log-errors-warnings-and-info-in-my-plugins-to-a-craft-log-file) article:

> If you want a log item to appear regardless of whether devMode is
>   enabled, you can pass true as the third argument to the log() method.

```
SproutActivePlugin::log('Log this with or without devMode enabled.', LogLevel::Info, true);
```

Is this accurate?

We've tried it. Doesn't seem to work as advertised. Nothing in the logs unless dev mode is turned on. And when it's turned on the Import plug-in hangs up. We're in a tough spot.

What else should we be looking for? What else can we try?

Craft CMS 2.6.2930 / Import 0.8.28 / PHP 5.6.10

**EDIT:**
We have increased memory_limit 10 fold (1280M)
We have increased max_execution_time 100 fold (30000)
We have increased max_input_time 100 fold (60000)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you want a log item to appear regardless of whether devMode is enabled, you can pass true as the third argument to the log() method.
>
> Is this accurate?

Yes. Logs will only get flushed to disk is a proper `craft()->end()` occurs, firing the `onEndRequest` event.  So if you're doing something in your plugin like calling PHP's `exit()` directly or there is some other logic that inadvertently kills the request, then they won't get written to the log file.

I'd suspect that's what you're running into.

Comment: Would the logs output fine with dev mode true? Because they do. I am trying to output logs from the Import `modifyImportRow` hook regardless of dev mode.

Comment: And you're looking in `craft/storage/runtime/logs/sproutactive.log`?  I just tested this in a test plugin's init method with `TestPlugin::log('Log this with or without devMode enabled.', LogLevel::Info, true);` and devMode disabled and got the expected `2016/09/13 23:19:27 [info] [plugin] [Forced] Log this with or without devMode enabled.` in `test.log`.

Comment: Yes, of course. If it ever gets written. But it doesn't. Something is screwy with the Import plug-in I think.

Comment: I tried - as you - putting the line into the Import plug-in init method, and indeed works as expected. So something else is happening. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Yeah, my guess is something in the plugin is improperly ending the request not giving Craft a chance to flush the logs. Still weird that it works fine with devMode on, though.